# Passing a pageContext array to Gatsby's pageQuery

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm struggling for hours to pass pageContext array to gatsby page Query

How I can pass an array to GraphQL?

```
query AllCategoriesQuery($id: Int!, $cat: Array) {
```

below is my complete query

```
export const query = graphql`
  query AllCategoriesQuery($id: Int!) {
    allStrapiChildcategories: allStrapiChildcategories(
      filter: { category: { id: { eq: $id } } }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          strapiId
          category {
            id
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
    allProducts: allStrapiProducts(
      filter: { childcategory: { id: { in: $cat } } }
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          strapiId
          childcategory {
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to pass an array using `pageContext` and GraphQL.

Try this:

```
query AllCategoriesQuery($id: Int!, $cat: [Int!]!) {}
```

IN that way, you are defining a list of integers that are non-nullable (marked as the exclamation mark, `!`), which means that is a mandatory field.

In GraphQL, they are called "lists" instead of arrays although the analogy is not completely precise. The list keeps items in an order. In SDL (Schema Definition Language) the listed modifier is written as square brackets with the wrapped instance of the type in the bracket.

More information about GraphQL Schema: https://graphql.org/learn/schema/

Comment: i'm getting this error Variable "$cat" of type "[String!]!" used in position expecting type "[Int]".

Comment: I supposed that `$cat` was an array of strings so I used `[String!]!`. Looking at your filter in `filter: { childcategory: { id: { in: $cat } } }` I guess it will be an array of integers. I've updated my answer adding the type: `$cat: [Int!]!`.

Comment: Thanks @Ferran, i'm gettign this format ["1234","2245","3567"] in pageContext $cat

Comment: i'm getting this now! 
Variable "$cat" got invalid value "childCategories"; Expected type Int. Int cannot represent non-integer value: "childCategories"

This can happen when you or a plugin/theme explicitly defined the GraphQL schema for this GraphQL object type via the schema customization API and "childCategories" doesn't match the (scalar) type of "Variable "$cat" got invalid value "childCategories"; Expected type Int. Int".

Comment: Never seen this before. Could you try changing the `$cat: [Int!]!` by `$cat: [Float!]!`? And another question, does all your `allProducts` has a category to be filtered?

Comment: error    Variable "$cat" of type "[Float!]!" used in position expecting type "[Int]", Yes there is childcategory object

Comment: Sorry for this trial and error. Never faced that issue. Could you try now using: `$cat: [Int!]` ?

Comment: btw, this query works query MyQuery {
  allStrapiProducts(filter: {childcategory: {id: {in: [864,865]}}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        childcategory{
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: inside graphql playground

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217758/discussion-between-ferran-buireu-and-yasir).